# Group representation projector in Maschke’s theorem by direct computation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

In the proof of the [Maschke’s theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem#Proofs),
$$p:=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}gp_0g^{-1}.$$
We can demonstrate $p$ is a projector by showing $pV\subset W$ and $p|W=\text{Id}$. However, I would like to show directly that
$p^2=p$ with the definition purely from the operator arithmetic.
$$p^2 = \frac1{|G|^2}\sum_{g,h\in G}gp_0g^{-1}hp_0h^{-1}.$$
I am having trouble getting $g^{-1}h$ to identity in some sense. Can someone elucidate the direct computation?

Comment: Are you sure the ‘product’ after your sum sign is correct? For $p^2$ is a composition of maps.

Comment: @NickyHekster: It seems so. The $g$ is a shorthand for $\rho(g)$ which is a linear transform or just a matrix. The products can be interpreted as true matrix products. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the particular property of concern of $G$  is not defined by itself but rather is determined completely in relation to and by its effect on $W$. There is no way to prove the theorem only manipulating $g\in G$ and not involving $W$.